# Send a Canvas to Facebook post with FB.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

I'm using [facebook UI](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui), to share content generated in my web to Facebook Pages. The content I want to share is a Canvas, that changes dynamically with the user interaction.

so I could easily convert this Canvas in Image with the next code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_current_athlete");
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```

The thing is that seems that facebook UI doesn't allow you to send data, or an octet stream, but only a static URL to a picture. As in the example:

```
FB.ui({
method: 'feed',
name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
caption: 'Reference Documentation',
description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'},
```

I could download the picture with this code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_current_athlete");
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");              
window.location.href = image;
```

But of course this download it in the client, and I would need that picture in the server to serve it with a static URL to facebook UI.

Is there a way to send an image as data to facebook post using faceobok UI or something else that makes easy to share a canvas to facebook?.

Thanks in advance, 
luchux.

Comment: I haven't finished tested this yet so i won't put it as an answer, but I am attempting the same with the following concept.https://coderwall.com/p/4qpmfw

Comment: Had a look, and seems like is not using the Facebook Feed dialog (faceook.UI function), but just a post. Moreover, he has some errors in the login so is not working. Thanks for the approach though.

Comment: Yeah, it needs an update to obtaining the access token.

Answer (score 0):

With the Feed/Feed Dialog - **No**. You can add the `picture` as a link only.

I'm not sure if the `feed` is more relevant or not in your case, but if you can use [/photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/), then the image data can be used to upload the picture. But of-course a feed will not be publish instead a photo will be added to your album and the story like: "user added a new photo" will be published on the wall.

But if your motive is to publish a feed, you cant use the picture data; you have to have a picture url. Another trick- you can first add a photo to facebook, then use that image in your feed.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Liked the idea of the trick. Will explore it a bit.  Hope not generating to much noise in the user facebook Page. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if its closed. I am wondering if probably someone has a different/alternative solution. cheers!

Comment: here trying same trick. but looks like the FB connection hang with a `net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when posting from canvas. But would like to have feedback of other people too.